# Show a new form after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to realize a 3-step form system. Basically, when you load the page, the first step of the form is displayed. Once completed and after the user has clicked on the "next step" button, form number 2 appears, and so on.

But I'm stuck on JS code. I do not know how to go about it.

My logic was simply to put parent elements (.step) in display: none, and after the user clicked the button, make the next step in display: block. What do you think ?

(This is obviously a prototype and divs will be replaced by )

### [My codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqBKNp)

HTML:

```
<div class="steps">
  <div class="step step1">
    Step 1/3
  </div>
  <div class="step step2">
    Step 2/3
  </div>
  <div class="step step3">
    Step 3/3
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn next-step">Next step</button>
```

CSS:

```
.step {
  display: none;

  &.is-active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Javascript (ES5/6), not jQuery

```
const btnStep = document.querySelector('.next-step');
const steps   = [].slice.call(document.querySelector('.steps').children);

btnStep.addEventListener('click', () =>
  steps.forEach(step => {
    // if (step.classList.contains('is-active')) {
    //   step.classList.remove('is-active')
    // }
    step.nextElementSibling.classList.add('is-active')

  })
)
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you facing? What did you try?

Comment: Loading up your codepen makes it infinitely refresh the page, please change it so it doesnt

Comment: My codepen works well at home

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a step counter. You should count the steps in js and put them in a variable called something like "numberOfSteps" so you can always add more steps. Then make two methods, one for incrementing and one for decrementing and change the counter accordingly. And then if (stepCounter === numberOfSteps), show the submit button.

Try to put all the logic in different functions and call them with the corresponding event handler (on click, etc.)

Hope this gets you on your way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what kind of behavior u want after the third step

But here is my solution tho im not sure this is exactly how u want it to work
https://jsfiddle.net/b5kvksau/

```
  var x = 1;

  function ini() {

    if (x == 1) {
      document.querySelector(".step1").classList.toggle("is-active");
      document.querySelector(".step2").classList.toggle("is-active");
      x++;
      console.log(x);
    } else if (x == 2) {
      document.querySelector(".step2").classList.toggle("is-active");

      document.querySelector(".step3").classList.toggle("is-active");
      x++;
      console.log(x);
    } else if (x == 3) {
      document.querySelector(".step3").classList.toggle("is-active");
      document.querySelector(".hello-world").innerHTML = "All done!";
      x = 5; // Add your desired execution after 3/3 steps of the form are completed
    }
  }
```

at "x=5" just add ur code for when the form is done, if its gonna be a redirect or whatever

Its very simple but the simpler it is the easier it is to debug and implement

Answer (score 0):

i HAd a little time so i came to an easy solution here http://codepen.io/AAnkudovich/pen/BWbaEp

on button click call the function an add active class to first element as it will be the starting point

```
<div class="steps">
 <div class=" is-active step1">
  Step 1/3
</div>
<div class="step step2">
  Step 2/3
</div>
<div class="step step3">
 Step 3/3
</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn next-step" onclick="stepnext()">Next step</button>
```

and this is the function to go into your js

```
 function stepnext() {

  document.getElementsByClassName('is-active')[0].classList.add('step');
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('is-active');
  elem[0].nextSibling.nextSibling.classList.add('is-active');
  document.getElementsByClassName('is-active')[0].classList.remove('is-active');


}
```

Comment: i added an if statement in the pen not to proceed if at the end of your divs